# Uploading an image to Microsoft Cognitive Services?

Tags: c#, computer-vision, uri, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to post an image to the Computer Vision API of [Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc/console). It requires me to upload the image as an url. I have the uploaded image by the user with an URI like http://localhost:9000/content/8a684db8?file=IMG-20160503-WA0002.jpg on my local pc. I tried the obvious but that doesn't work. How to pass the image to their API?

They also mention I can post the image as a raw binary but I am unable to get how to get going.

PS: You can get the subscription keys using the free subscriptions if you want to test it for some other cases.

Comment: I came across this question when looking for a python version of the answer, and the solution I've managed is:

`with open(fl_input, "rb") as image_stream: read_results = client.read_in_stream(image=image_stream, raw=True)`

Answer (score 1):

localhost is 127.0.0.1, e.g. your PC when accessing from your PC. You should pass external IP of your PC in the internet

Comment: That is correct, the address is not reachable by the service as you original specified.
Note that you can also send the image up in the body of the HTTP request instead, which might be easier than getting your machine reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to get a solution. Didn't post my answer sorry.

[Microsoft Computer Vision Documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api/documentation/getstarted/getstartedvisionapiforwindows) This shows how to call their API's using the nuget Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.The below code uploads and analyzes a locally stored image to the analyze endpoint of the Computer Vision API service.

```
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision; 
using Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Vision.Contract; 

private async Task<AnalysisResult> UploadAndAnalyzeImage(string imageFilePath)
{
    //
    // Create Project Oxford Computer Vision API Service client
    //
    VisionServiceClient VisionServiceClient = new VisionServiceClient(SubscriptionKey);
    Log("VisionServiceClient is created");

    using (Stream imageFileStream = File.OpenRead(imageFilePath))
    {
        //
        // Analyze the image for all visual features
        //
        Log("Calling VisionServiceClient.AnalyzeImageAsync()...");
        VisualFeature[] visualFeatures = new VisualFeature[] { VisualFeature.Adult, VisualFeature.Categories, VisualFeature.Color, VisualFeature.Description, VisualFeature.Faces, VisualFeature.ImageType, VisualFeature.Tags };
        AnalysisResult analysisResult = await VisionServiceClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(imageFileStream, visualFeatures);
        return analysisResult;
    }
```

}

[On this Git Repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Vision/Windows) you can see some samples.Here you also get how you can handle client errors and exceptions.