# Python method to upload an image to Microsoft Cognitive Vision from local machine

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I have been writing python code to pass a folder containing images for analysis using Cognitive Vision API. My code works fine when I use an URL for any image hosted online.

However, I am having some difficulties while passing images from the local machine. I have tried converting file paths to URL using:

```
    imageurl = pathlib.Path(path).as_uri()
```

Is there any way of doing it? I have around 2000 images to analyze.

This post [Uploading an image to Microsoft Cognitive Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685242/uploading-an-image-to-microsoft-cognitive-services) provides some insight on how to do it using C# but I did not find any similar documentation for python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just getting a path as a URL does not magically make it available on the Internet. Is there a reason you just don't upload the images somewhere?

Comment: I tried uploading the images on dropbox but the image file name changes after upload. I have a list containing all the image filenames but I can't use that list if the filenames are changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Computer Vision API documentation states the following:

> Request body:
>
> Input passed within the POST body. Supported input methods: raw image binary or image URL.

Thus, if the image is not available online (through a URL), you need to pass the raw binary as the body of your POST request.

Here's an example, using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

```
import requests

img_filename = '<your image path and filename>'
with open(img_filename, 'rb') as f:
    img_data = f.read()

# you'll need to define the following variables yourself:
# - params
# - header

r = requests.post(api_url,
                  params=params,
                  headers=header,
                  data=img_data)
```

I also have a blog post that might help you out: [Using Microsoft Cognitive Services to perform OCR on images](http://www.speeckaert.io/blog/articles/using-microsoft-cognitive-services-to-perform-ocr-on-images.html). This contains example code in Python for uploading an image and retrieving the results. It uses the OCR part of the Computer Vision API, but it should be similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at your blog post. I am using https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze as the api_url but it caused bad request for url: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze?language=en&visualFeatures=Description%2C+Categories%2C+color%2C+adult

Answer (score 5):

Moreover to what was said before need to change from 'json' to 'octet-stream' in the 'headers'-part. Following the documentation style, it should look like this.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXX', 
}
try:    
    body = open('User/........', "rb").read()
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/emotion/v1.0/recognize?%s" % body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read() 
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
import urllib, json
import requests

img_filename = 'RH_Louise_Lillian_Gish.jpg'
with open(img_filename, 'rb') as f:
    img_data = f.read()

# Replace the subscription_key string value with your valid subscription key.
subscription_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

## Request headers.
header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
}

# Request parameters.
params = urllib.urlencode({
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
})

api_url = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?%s"%params

r = requests.post(api_url,
#                  params=params,
                  headers=header,
                  data=img_data)

print (r.json())
```